# Free throw rules

Tags: rules, officiating, basketball

Scenario:  High School Girls basketball game. Foul happens, 10th foul for the team that fouled. Double bonus for other team. First shot is missed. Shooting team rebounds shoots and makes the basket. Is given 2 points. Questions being asked why? Refs conference, Points are left on the board for the rebound shot and the team originally shooting free throw is then allowed to shoot her second shoot and makes it. Why was the rebound shot permitted in the first place. Double bonus free throws, not a three point shot foul. and they were rewarded for the refs not knowing what the foul count was.

We were told per the rule the two points had to remain on the board even though it was technically a dead ball shot.

Please help with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The ref's were wrong, and probably left them on the board simply because they didn't know what else to do.

> **Section I-Positions**
>
> a. When a free throw is awarded, an official shall put the ball in
>   play by placing it at the disposal of the free throw shooter. The
>   shooter shall be within the upper half of the free throw circle. The
>   same procedure shall be followed each time a free throw is
>   administered.
>
> b. During a free throw for a personal foul, each of the spaces nearest
>   the endline must be occupied by an opponent of the free throw shooter.
>   Teammates of the free throw shooter must occupy the next adjacent
>   spaces on each side. Only one of the third adjacent spaces may be
>   occupied by an opponent of the free throw shooter. It is not mandatory
>   that either of the third adjacent spaces be occupied. No teammates of
>   the free throw shooter are permitted in these spaces.
>
> c. All other players not stationed on the free throw lane must be at
>   least six feet from the free throw lane lines and three feet from the
>   free throw circle.
>
> d. If the ball is to become dead after the last free throw, players
>   shall not take positions along the free throw lane. No players shall
>   be allowed inside the free throw line extended while a free throw is
>   being attempted under these conditions.
>
> **PENALTIES:**
>
> (1) If the violation is by either team and the free throw attempt is
>   successful or occurs on the first of multiple free throw attempts, it
>   is ignored.
>
> (2) If the violation is by an opponent of the free throw shooter and
>   the free throw attempt is unsuccessful, a substitute free throw
>   attempt is awarded.
>
> (3) If the violation is by a teammate of the free throw shooter, it is
>   a violation as soon as the free throw is attempted. The ball is
>   awarded to his opponent at the free throw line extended.
>
> **Section II-Shooting of Free Throw**
>
> a. The free throw(s) awarded because of a personal foul shall be
>   attempted by the offended player.
>
> *EXCEPTIONS:*
>
> (1) If the off ended player is fouled and is subsequently ejected from
>   the game before shooting the awarded free throw(s), he must
>   immediately leave the court and another of the four players on the
>   court will be designated by the opposing coach to shoot such free
>   throw(s).
>
> (2) if the offended player is injured and cannot shoot the awarded
>   free throw(s), the opposing coach shall select, from his opponent's
>   bench, the player who will replace the injured player. That player
>   will attempt the free throw(s) and the injured player will not be
>   permitted to re-enter the game. The substitute must remain in the game
>   until the next dead ball.
>
> (3) If the offended player is injured and unable to shoot the awarded
>   free throw(s) due to any unsportsmanlike act, his coach may designate
>   any eligible member of the squad to attempt the free throw(s). The
>   injured player will be permitted to re-enter the game.
>
> (4) If the offended player is disqualified and unable to shoot the
>   awarded free throw(s), his coach shall designate an eligible
>   substitute from the bench. That substitute will attempt the free
>   throw(s) and cannot be removed until the next dead ball.
>
> (5) Away from play foul (Rule 12B-Section Xa(l).
>
> b. A free throw attempt, personal or technical, shall neither be legal
>   nor count unless an official handles the ball and is also in the free
>   throw area when the foul try is attempted.
>
> c. A player awarded two free throws must attempt both even though the
>   first attempt is nullified by a violation by an offensive player.
>
> **Section III-Time Limit**
>
> Each free throw attempt shall be made within 10 seconds after the ball
>   has been placed at the disposal of the free thrower.
>
> **Section IV-Next Play**
>
> After a successful free throw which is not followed by another free
>   throw, the ball shall be put into play by a throw-in, as after a field
>   goal if the try is successful.
>
> EXCEPTION: After a free throw for a foul which occurs during a dead
>   ball which immediately precedes any period, the ball shall be put into
>   play by the team entitled to the throw-in in the period which follows
>   (See Rule 6-Section I-b).

These are the official rules.  Basically the ref's were wrong in awarding the 2 points.

[Source](http://nbahoopsonline.com/History/Leagues/NBA/Rules/Freethrows.html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what rules your league operated under, and I don't know high school girl's basketball; but if they use FIBA rules or a modification thereof, there are specific procedures for correcting errors.

In the [FIBA Rulebook](http://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2014/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf):

> **Art. 44 Correctable errors**
>
> > 44.1. Definition
> >
> > Officials may correct an error if a rule is inadvertently disregarded
> >     in the following situations only:
> >
> > - Awarding an unmerited free throw(s).
> > - Failure to award a merited free throw(s).
> > - Erroneous awarding or cancelling of a point(s).
> > - Permitting the wrong player to attempt a free throw(s).

This falls under the third category, the erroneous awarding of points.

The procedure here:

> 44.2.1. To be correctable the above-mentioned errors must be recognized by the officials, commissioner, if present, or table
>   officials before the ball becomes live following the first dead ball
>   after the game clock has started following the error.
>
> 44.2.2. An official may stop the game immediately upon recognition of a correctable error, as long as neither team is placed at a
>   disadvantage.
>
> 44.2.3. Any fouls committed, points scored, time used, additional activity which may have occurred after the error has occurred and
>   before its recognition, shall remain valid.

In the case you noted above, the error was noticed before the next time the ball became live, so the official should have stopped the game immediately, corrected the error, then continued play (with the second free throw).

I suspect the referees felt that the rebound and shot meant that a 'live ball' situation had occurred and thus the play wasn't correctable any longer.  However, they have until the *next* live ball beyond that, even if they ruled the incorrect live ball counted as a live ball situation - which it probably shouldn't.